# help needed with quick IE7 CSS z-index problem

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck on an ie7 css curiousity...

try typing something in the search box (on ie7) ont eh below page, the z-index doesn't seem to be working like it does for other pop-up type elements on the same page.

http://bit.ly/cPzgom

I usually try to avoid instance-specific questions like this but it's got me really frustrated!

thanks!

Comment: Dont have an answer right now, but this can also be repro'd on IE8 in compatibility mode. Looks find in IE8 on standards mode (default)

Comment: it works fine in ie8, and doesn't trigger quirks mode in either ie7 or ie8...

Comment: I found http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/40-how-z-index-works/ really helpful when tackling z-indexes. When they didn't work for me I had usually forgotten some container-element CSS, which the other browsers were correcting but not IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the div for the floating drag search results box in the context of `<body>`, right now in ie7 it's nested inside the div with id="search_box".

Comment: think something might have been deleted from your answer there, "in the context of : "

Comment: thanks steve this worked perfectly. I then used jquery's offset (http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to then set the position.